# Why are drinking laws so strict in the USA?

Tags: united-states, law, policy, us-state-laws, alcohol

In the USA, alcohol laws are very strict and specific, while in most other parts of the world they are very lax.  What's the reason?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part of those laws is strict (compared to other countries)?

Comment: For example, minimum drinking age is 21 in USA.

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._history_of_alcohol_minimum_purchase_age_by_state

Comment: Canadian liquor legislation can be highly regulated as well though I believe most provinces are at 19, barring Quebec at 18.  Britain used to have bars shutting down at 10:30 pm.  Ditto Finland.  So, while there are certainly reasons why the US has fairly restrictive laws, they are NOT uniquely restrictive either, especially not if you compare to some other Western countries some 30+ years back.

Comment: There are many local laws that are substantially more restrictive than just looking at the minimum drink age - there are counties that don't allow the sale of liquor at all, and Utah has some pretty stringent liquor laws as well. If I recall, they can only have 3.2%ABV or lower on tap - when I visited they had to sell us a bottle of beer for us to pour ourselves to be higher. Liquor stores I think have to be state owned. We couldn't buy growlers from the bar, we had to go to a legally separate but colocated gift shop.

Comment: The US drinking law is not strict.  It is restrictive, but not strict.  Yes.  The drinking age is very high.  BUT underage drinking is rampant, and is hardly ever punished.  If you want to see strict laws... You should see the drug laws of singapore...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher 30 years back, however, the US was just past the beginning of its transition to a drinking age of 21. Enforcement was quite lax through the end of the 1980s, at least, in the places where I lived at the time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "frame challenge" aspect of this answer is to note that, while the USA is stricter than many European countries, it is less strict than many other countries. Many majority Muslim countries ban alcohol outright, or put far greater limits on its sale than the USA.

However drinking culture is more restricted in the USA than in Europe. The age at which you can purchase alcohol is only a little higher in the USA, but there is a difference. Much of this can be traced to the consequences of Prohibition, and the culture in which Prohibition arose.

There is a religious tradition of Protestant piety in the USA, in which personal behaviour is emphasised over ritual. This led to movements that opposed alcohol absolutely in the 19th century and culminated in the constitutional banning of all social alcohol in 1920.

Even after repeal of these laws in the 1930s, the culture of alchol consumption remained very different. The cultural effect of prohibition extends to the present day.

Comment: There are also revenue reasons.  Many eastern states used to allow liquor to be sold only by state-owned stores, at artificially-high prices.  (I think that's still the case in at least some places, though I haven't been back to check.)  By contrast, in many western states, you just buy it at the supermarket,

Comment: Among western democracies, America does have a pretty prudish attitude towards alcohol. Also, @jamesqf; They're called [ABC States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcoholic_beverage_control_state), and there are currently 17 of them.

Comment: The constitutional amendment didn't ban Alcohol, but moved the regulation of Alcohol from the state level to the Federal Level.  Congress had to pass laws which would ban it.

Comment: True, but the purpose of the amendment was entirely so that Congress would then prohibit alcohol.  None of the states voting for the amendment though "okay, now congress will make alcohol *less* regulated.

Comment: @jamesqf It is not necessary for a state to sell alcohol themselves to have [restrictions on pricing](https://alcoholpolicy.niaaa.nih.gov/apis-policy-topics/wholesale-pricing-practices-and-restrictions/3) or to have state [excise taxes](https://alcoholpolicy.niaaa.nih.gov/apis-policy-topics/beer/30).

Comment: @hszmv It did ban it and stated it very clearly. "After one year from the ratification of this article the manufacture, sale, or transportation of intoxicating liquors within, the importation thereof into, or the exportation thereof from the United States and all territory subject to the jurisdiction thereof for beverage purposes is hereby prohibited."

Comment: @hszmv by what line of reasoning do you reach the conclusion that the text "the manufacture, sale, or transportation of intoxicating liquors within, the importation thereof into, or the exportation thereof from the United States and all the territory subject to the jurisdiction thereof for beverage purposes is hereby prohibited" did not ban alcohol but only gave congress the power to pass laws to do so?  It absolutely does ban alcohol.  The second section is about details of enforcement, explicitly allowing states to enforce it as well as the federal government.

Answer (score 11):

The higher minimum legal age for alcohol use in the United States is tied directly into the low minimum driving ages.  The U.S. has the largest population of the Western World, and is fairly rural outside of the coastal regions (even then, some coastal states are not that densely populated).  This creates the need for lower minimum driving ages in these states.  Typically the minimum driving age in these states is 16 although some states allow for hardship license which allow for people as young as 14 to drive, usually in very rural states and usually only if a legal adult guardian is unable to drive; most of the other countries in the Western World don't issue drivers' licenses until 17-18.

Drivers who are the minimum age of driving in any nation have the highest insurance premiums for a reason:  young and inexperienced drivers are some of the worst drivers.  Since the driving age in the United States is low, a high alcohol legal age is seen as a trade off of sorts.

[In 1984, the United States Congress passed the National Minimum Drinking Age Act, which withheld **10% of federal highway funding** from states that did not maintain a minimum legal drinking age of 21.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Dakota_v._Dole) As a result, the current legal minimum is set as a condition of Interstate Highway Funding (roads in the U.S. are usually funded by the states, but the Federal Government funds interstates because they were considered defense infrastructure that was vital to mobilizing troops in an invasion of the U.S. or a disaster).  This gets around the state issue by tying payment to states restricting alcohol sales to 21 years or older.  Since every state has roads that are funded by the Interstate System the states all upped the age to 21 to get their road funding.

Comment: This answer would be improved by some citations

Comment: @JaredSmith:  Any particular element you need cited?

Comment: Sure. The statement that young drivers are worse drivers in various countries, that alcohol impairs driving, driving ages being higher in other first world countries, etc. I still think it makes a good point even without the citations, but would likely be a definitive answer with them.

Comment: @divibisan:  Your assumption is correct.  It's mostly an inexperience factor, but drivers who are the minimum age of driving in any nation have the highest insurance primium for a reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith: First issue is based on insurance premiums, second is a known fact, third is based on knowledge of U.K. driving ages and German Driving ages (the latter is personal experience as my high school hosted a German exchange student, who used his time in America to get a license so he could drive a car on an international license upon returning home 2 years before his buddies.).

Comment: The minimum drinking age of 21 was the result of the early campaigns of [Mothers Against Drunk Driving](https://www.madd.org/), which was founded in 1980 by a mother whose daughter was killed by a drunk driver.  Prior to the nationwide drinking age of 21, various states had various minimum drinking ages.  Young people would arbitrage these drinking ages by driving across state lines, getting alcohol (or drinking alcohol), and then driving back.

Comment: It should be noted that the nationwide drinking age of 21 came about as a result of threats to remove federal highway funding from any state where the minimum age was not at least 21

Comment: That many countries don't grant licenses until 18 and also permit alcohol for 18-year-olds does not explain why US licenses being available to 16-year-olds requires a drinking age of 21 as compared to 18.  In those countries, 18-to-20-year-olds are trusted to drive or drink, but not both.  In the US, people of that age are not afforded the same level of trust.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the fact that [10% of American adults waste their lives in a state of perpetual inebriation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/09/25/think-you-drink-a-lot-this-chart-will-tell-you/), leading to a corresponding loss in the GDP and fracturing many families, destroying life, and contributing also to a conservatively estimated [quarter of a trillion dollars](https://www.cdc.gov/features/costsofdrinking/index.html) in additional losses annually, might help to contextualize the USA's relatively conservative stance and strictness about alcohol.

Those who claim that alcohol is not addictive or who promote the punchline "drink responsibly" are probably dodging the fact (derived from the Washington Post source above) that at least 88% of alcoholic beverages in this country are consumed by **alcoholics**.

It's addiction industry at its finest, and US citizens are unquestionably wise insofar as they restrict and curtail it.

[Relative to most of Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_alcohol_consumption_per_capita), U.S. consumption appears to be below average but not extremely low (9.2 liters per capita annually). It would be interesting to see a breakdown similar to the Washington Post article for other countries.

Comment: Can you put these numbers in an international context? How do they compare with European countries (for example)? And does increasing the drinking age help reduce the number of addicts in later life?

Comment: I've added one source for now. I don't have as much info on European countries yet, as I haven't researched the global side of this in depth yet.

Comment: Thanks, [the WHO](http://gamapserver.who.int/mapLibrary/app/searchResults.aspx) has graphs on alcohol use disorders but they're pretty dated.

Comment: Anyone who can fill in those gaps will be much appreciated. Alcohol consumption suffers from a pretty embarassing paucity of medical data for being quite possibly the #1 addictive pastime in the world.

Comment: The tone of this answer is harsh and judgemental, but I cannot say that it is factually wrong.  I think that the answer could be improved by a more neutral tone.